# Unable to execute redirection in chroot environment

Tags: linux, io-redirection, chroot, debootstrap

I've set up full working debootstrap-ed arm chroot environment. I can `chroot` in it, run commands, etc.

I am making a script that will customize chroot env, but I struggle with this.

For example:

```
chroot $target_dir echo this is a test > /tmp/test
```

Can anyone explain to me, why within this example I get output written on my host environment, not in chrooted?

Just to mention, I could execute f.e.

```
echo this is a test > $target_dir/tmp/test
```

but I would like to know why chrooted execution 'fails'

Edit:

This also works:

```
chroot $target_dir /bin/bash -c "echo test > /tmp/test"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run:

```
chroot $target_dir echo this is a test > /tmp/test
```

The `> /tmp/test` happens "for" the chroot command, much as if you had written:

```
> /tmp/test chroot $target_dir echo this is a test
```

If you want the redirection to happen inside of the chroot command, one way would be:

```
chroot $target_dir sh -c 'echo this is a test > /tmp/test'
```

... as this puts `sh` inside the chroot, letting echo see the correct redirected directory.

Answer (score 3):

The redirection isn't actually occurring inside `chroot`. `> /tmp/test` is handled by whatever shell you are using. If you actually passed `> /tmp/test` to *`chroot`*, then it would get passed to `echo` and you'd see

```
this is a test > /tmp/test
```

on your terminal. You shell, of course, isn't getting `chroot`ed, so it's perfectly fine with opening `/tmp/test`. Then, the shell `exec`s the `chroot` executable, which calls the `chroot` system call and then `exec`s into `echo`, which finally writes to the fd. All through this, the original file descriptor that your (un`chroot`ed) shell opened is never modified, so your `chroot`ed `echo` is able to write to it.

This is a deliberate feature. A process outside the `chroot` is allowed to open files, and then its `chroot`ed children can only access those files outside the `chroot` that the parent process deigned to pass to them.

If you want the redirection to take place *inside* the chroot, you need to spawn a shell that knows how to interpret it:

```
chroot $dir bash -c "echo this is a test > /tmp/test"
```

The order of operations is now: `fork` (with default stdin, stdout, and stderr), `exec` `chroot`, `chroot` (now inside chroot), `exec` `bash` (knows how to handle redirection), `fork` (implementation detail of `bash`), open file, `exec` `echo` (with new stdout).